# Recharts stacked area show wrong yAxis labels?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-component, recharts

[image]

http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/StackedAreaChart

This example shows, and I also made pointers that the value of the values do not correspond to the label why is this happening?
Is there any explanation and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the tooltip using its [`content` prop](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Tooltip#content).

The component passed there receives the same props as the Rechart's `Tooltip` so you only need to override the needed and bypass the rest. If you don't want to change the visual part of tooltip you can return another `Tooltip` at the end.

```js
// Do not pass the `content` since it causes a recursive rendering
const CumulativeTooltip = ({ content, payload, ...props }) => {
  const values = payload.map(({ value }) => value);
  const cumulativePayload = payload.reduce((result, item, index) => result.concat({
    ...item,
    value: values.slice(0, index + 1).reduce((sum, v) => sum + v, 0)
  }), []);

  return (<Tooltip {...props} payload={cumulativePayload} />);
}

// ... later in chart

<Tooltip content={<CumulativeTooltip/>}/>
```

[Playground](https://jsfiddle.net/268mjLfz/2/)